# Why is my iPhone screen stuck on the 'connect to iTunes' screen

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4S is stuck on the "Connect to iTunes" screen after trying to install the iOS 8 update.Why is my iPhone screen stuck on the 'connect to iTunes' screen